# How to remove a crypto_LUKS from a device

Tags: hard-disk, cryptsetup

In a moment of inattention, I ran luksFormat on /dev/sda instead of on /dev/sda**1**. Now I would like to undo that operation. Checking man for cryptsetup doesn't reveal an obvious method.

`lsblk -f1 shows the following:

```
sda          crypto_LUKS                       45e143e4-7d5b-4f20-b552-f301ced442f4 
└─sda1       crypto_LUKS                       55c24c05-d113-4df5-2715-f0d4072f5343
```

Normally, when I do this, there is no output to the right of sda. That's the state where I would like to end up after correcting my mistake.

I can lose sda1 at this point too. There is nothing important on it and I can recreate it in a minute. In short, I would like to start over with this block device after my mistake. However, running `gdisk /dev/sda` and making a new partition table and a new partition does not remove the crypto_LUKS from sda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's no issue with recovering/keeping any data on the drive, and using `gdisk` (or equivalent) directly to make a new partition table does not work, you can wipe the header (and any partition tables) on the block device with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=8M count=4`.
That should let you create a fresh partition table on the device with `gdisk` afterwards.

NOTE: This operation is *destructive*, so make sure to assign the correct device to the `of=` option!